# what should I do to specify the output dir when using rust command to generate latex doc

Tags: rust

I am using this rust(`v1.69.0`) code to genrate latex docs in macOS 13.2:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("xelatex")
        .arg("/Users/John/source/dolphin/XiaoqiangResume/JiangxiaoqiangResume-en.tex")
        .arg("-output-directory=/Users/John/source/reddwarf/backend/cv-render/output/")
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");
}
```

but the output dir `/Users/John/source/reddwarf/backend/cv-render/output/` did not contains the xelatex compile output files, what should I do to specify the output files? When I using this command to compile latex file in macOS terminal:

```
xelatex /Users/John/source/dolphin/XiaoqiangResume/JiangxiaoqiangResume-en.tex -output-directory=/Users/John/source/reddwarf/backend/cv-render/output/
```

it works fine, and successfully generate the output files in destination folder.

Comment: Have you able to run xelatex with those arguments without rust ? With the same user privilege? You can see if there is an error from the subprocess with this code : `io::stderr().write_all(&output.stderr).unwrap()`

Comment: without the out dir args this code works fine, but generate the docs in root folder, I want to specify the destination folder because I want to provide the render service, there contains many users. put all files in root folder seems ugly.

Answer (score 0):

change the command like this, and make sure the destination folder exists:

```
let output = Command::new("xelatex")
        .arg("-output-directory")
        .arg("/Users/John/source/reddwarf/backend/cv-render/output/")
        .arg("/Users/John/source/dolphin/XiaoqiangResume/JiangxiaoqiangResume-en.tex")
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");
```